# Crear una tabla con Javascript, multiples tag th

Tags: javascript, json, html-tabla

Tengo que generar una tabla con javascript en la que me salgan con los respectivos titulos que los he puesto en un array y luego mostrar el JSON de diferentes ciudades con cada tiempo que tiene. Pero tengo el problema que me generar varias veces los tags th generada. Os dejo como se ve: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código que he estado haciendo:

```
function generarTabla(){
// Obtener la referencia del elemento body
var container=document.getElementById("exercici6");

var tabla = document.createElement("table");
var tblbody = document.createElement("tbody");
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
var titols = ["Nombre","Tiempo","Ciudad"];
var json = {"coord":{"lon":139.69,"lat":35.69},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":292.39,"feels_like":287.59,"temp_min":292.04,"temp_max":292.59,"pressure":1012,"humidity":72},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":8.7,"deg":210},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1589046064,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8074,"country":"JP","sunrise":1589053226,"sunset":1589103294},"timezone":32400,"id":1850147,"name":"Tokyo","cod":200}

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
    var hilera2 = document.createElement("tr");

    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        var titol = document.createElement("th");
        var celda = document.createElement("td");
        var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("celda en la hilera "+i+", columna "+j);
        var textoTitol = document.createTextNode(titols[j]);

        titol.appendChild(textoTitol);
        celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
        hilera2.appendChild(titol)
        hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }
    thead.appendChild(hilera2);
    tblbody.appendChild(hilera);
}

tabla.appendChild(thead);
tabla.appendChild(tblbody);

container.appendChild(tabla);

tabla.setAttribute("border","2");
```

}

Comment: Hola amigo, una recomendacion JSON.parse es innecesario en ese caso, puedes usar ese JSON sin parsearlo y con ese formato sin problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema ocurre cuando tratas de "dibujar" la cabecera de la tabla en el interior del segundo `for`. En ese momento estás generando un nuevo `th` por cada celda que agregas al cuerpo de la tabla. Moví esa parte del código un nivel más arriba y funcionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Borré esta linea del código: `var obj = JSON.parse(json);`

```js
function generarTabla(){
  // Obtener la referencia del elemento body
  var container=document.getElementById("exercici6");

  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var hilera2 = document.createElement("tr");  
  var titols = ["Nombre","Tiempo","Ciudad"];
  var json = {"coord":{"lon":139.69,"lat":35.69},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":292.39,"feels_like":287.59,"temp_min":292.04,"temp_max":292.59,"pressure":1012,"humidity":72},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":8.7,"deg":210},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1589046064,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8074,"country":"JP","sunrise":1589053226,"sunset":1589103294},"timezone":32400,"id":1850147,"name":"Tokyo","cod":200};

  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
    
    // thead
    var titol = document.createElement("th");
    var textoTitol = document.createTextNode(titols[i]);
    titol.appendChild(textoTitol);
    hilera2.appendChild(titol);

    // tbody
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        var celda = document.createElement("td");
        var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("celda en la hilera "+i+", columna "+j);

        celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
        hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }
    
    tblbody.appendChild(hilera);
  }
  
  thead.appendChild(hilera2);
  tabla.appendChild(thead);
  tabla.appendChild(tblbody);
  container.appendChild(tabla);
  tabla.setAttribute("border","2");
}

generarTabla();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="exercici6"></div>
</body>
</html>
```